# Safari and Firefox not displaying site correctly, but Chrome is working well

Tags: html, css, wordpress, w3c-validation

I have built my site with Wordpress using my own theme in Chrome. Considering Safari, Firefox and Chrome's similarities - I did not expect such a big discrepancy in how the site is displayed.

I'm guessing it is some kind of syntax error in how the files are loaded, but not sure. The CSS and JS files are loaded using the functions.php file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

The site in question: http://exeterentrepreneurs.com/dev/

Comment: From the console: `<source> element has no “src” attribute. Media resource load failed
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused
‘mozHidden’ and ‘mozVisibilityState’ are deprecated.  Please use the unprefixed ‘hidden’ and ‘visibilityState’ instead.`

Comment: Thanks @Igor I've looked into the error messages but am not sure what they refer to - any help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) You have many HTML markup errors,** such as these missing closing image tag errors:

```
<img src="http://example.com/..../event_feature-tick.png"<p>100% Free</p>
```

See the missing `>`in front of the `<p>` tag? It has to be:

```
<img src="http://example.com/..../event_feature-tick.png"><p>100% Free</p>
```

Fix all those image tag errors, and then use the W3 Code Validator to check for more. You can ignore for now errors such as "An img element must have an alt attribute...", but fix an missing closing `</div>` tag errors. Fix the above image tag errors first, and many of the other errors and warnings will fix themselves.

See [Showing results for  exeterentrepreneurs.com dev  - W3C Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fexeterentrepreneurs.com%2Fdev%2F&showsource=yes) and use it again after you fix some errors.

**2) You may also have Javascript errors.** Use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to check for Javascript and other console errors. The use of those dev tools are essential for web development work.